# Apache RewriteEngine

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite an URL like this
`http://domain1.com/some_directory/12345678?x=1/audio.mp3`
to an URL like this `http://domain2.com/12345678?x=1`.

I tried this rewrite rule `RewriteRule /some_directory/(.*)$/(.*).mp3 http://domain2.com/$1 [NC,L]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Error in your regex is `$`. Remove it. And also escaping the `/`

Comment: @noob I get an internal server error. :(

Comment: To be accurate you are only looking for that `number`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess by matching query string in a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(x=\d+)[^.]+\.mp3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^some_directory/(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1?%1 [NC,L,R=302,NE]
```